# Query error "Subquery returned more than 1 value..." Shouldn't "IN" solve this?

Tags: subquery

I have received great help here before, so I'm hoping someone can help me figure this out.  Can anyone tell me why Query #1 results in the error "Subquery returned more than 1 value..." but Query #2 works fine?  Since I am using "IN" instead of "=" to qualify the results I thought multiple values would be acceptable.

Any suggestions on how I can accomplish this?

```
--Query #1
SELECT _Column1_ from _View1_
WHERE
_Column2_ IN( CASE
WHEN ISNUMERIC(1000110) = 1 AND LEN(1000110) > 3
THEN (
SELECT  _Column2_
FROM    _Table1_
WHERE   _Column2_ = CONVERT(Int, LEFT(1000110, 4))
OR      _Column3_ = CONVERT(Int, LEFT(1000110, 4))
)
WHEN ISNUMERIC(1000110) = 1 AND LEN(1000110) <= 3
THEN 0
ELSE (SELECT _Column2_ from _Table1_)
END)
```

NOTE: In the final query, 1000110 will actually be a username variable that could return a numeric username or alpha numeric

```
--Query #2
WHEN ISNUMERIC(1000110) = 1 AND LEN(1000110) > 3
THEN CONVERT(Int, LEFT(1000110, 4))
WHEN ISNUMERIC(1000110) = 1 AND LEN(1000110) <= 3
THEN 0
ELSE (SELECT _Column2_ from _Table1_)
END)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT _Column2_ from _Table1_` most likely returns multiple resuluts. In this context only a single value is allowed.

As a test try `SELECT TOP(1) _Column2_ from _Table1_`

Comment: Yes, Select top(1) will fix the error, but eliminates the purpose of the query.  I need to have the CASE clause return ALL matching records, which is why I'm trying to use IN instead of =.  Any idea how to achieve the same result?

Comment: You're using your subquery as a part of CASE statement result which can return only scalar values (so technically in your case you can replace IN with =). If you want to return multiple results from the subquery - you have to JOIN it to main query, something like

`SELECT _View1_._Column1_, 
CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(1000110) = 1 AND LEN(1000110) > 3
THEN 0 ELSE _Table1_._Column2_

from _View1_ INNER JOIN _Table1_ ON [Some common column]`

Comment: I see now that using CASE eliminates the IN functionality. I think i'm going to have to look for another option to solve my particular problem, but the option you provide is definitely helpful.  Thanks!